# Mock function is not called with on click method with enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to just test that a function is indeed invoked when a click action occurs on a link in my component. I keep receiving the error
`Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.`
But it works correctly in the browser.

I thought maybe there was an issue with the test finding the id I was asking it to look for, but using other methods I see it was able to access the element just fine.

The component

```
import { toggleEditMode } from './otherFile.js'
class PersonalInformation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {editMode: false}
    this.toggleEditMode = toggleEditMode.bind(this);
  }

  render(){
   const { editMode } = this.state;
   return(
     <div>
{!editMode &&
            <div className="col-md-4 hidden-sm-down">
              <a
                id="editingToggleButton"
                className="display-block"
                role="button"
                href="javascript:void(0);"
                onClick={() => this.toggleEditMode()}
              >
                <span className="icon icon-sm dls-icon-edit" />
                <span className="pad-1-l">Edit</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          }
     </div>
)
}
}
```

The toggleEdit method

```
export function toggleEditMode() {
  this.setState({ editMode: !this.state.editMode })
}
```

The test

```
describe('edit', () => {
  it('should switch to editMode with click', () => {
  const toggleEditMode = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = mount(
    <PersonalInformation
      toggleEditMode={toggleEditMode}
    />
  );
    wrapper.find('#editingToggleButton').simulate('click');
    expect(toggleEditMode).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
}
```

I was able to log what it finds when using the find method and it returns the right element. But I can't seem to figure out how "it was not called".

Answer (score 1):

In the test `file` you have assigned the mock function to the `props` but in the `component` you are using it as a class function.

So, in the test file, when the user clicks the HTML element it fires the class function and not the mocked one.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, though now I'm running into a different error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`, referring to when the function tries to change the state. I tried adding ` wrapper.setState({editMode: false})` before wrapper.find, but it doesn't seem to help :(

Comment: Shouldn't be the case though, as you have declared `wrapper`

Comment: That's what I thought, and the function is bound to the component as well.